# Nodejs module memory leak

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks, node-modules

I have a problem in node which is leaking a lot of memory, the problem is summarized as below

```
module.exports = function (object) {
    this.myfunc = ()=>{
      ...dosomestuff
    }
}

let myObj = new MyModule( {randomObject});
```

Up to this part nothing gets leaked, the problem is that when I do

```
myObj.myfunc()
```

the {randomObject} gets leaked, also in my myfunc I dont even use the object parameter, that parameter was used by other functions that I didnt even call.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What are you using to measure your memory usage?

Comment: Chrome inspector, I'm doing node --inspect filename, and I'm using the memory heap

Comment: and how aggressive is the leak?

Comment: Very, the objects are big and the function is used very frequently

Comment: If the objects are accessible to other parts of your application, then as they are created in memory they will not be garbage collected until they are unreachable. That is the basic reason why a memory leak happens in gc languages, so you should consider why you are instantiating so many of these functions (and figure out a way to reuse the already existing ones?), or rearchitect the object to not take up so much memory, and figure out a way to get it garbage collected (like assigning it to `null` when you're done with it or something--might be hacky, but it would work).

Comment: They are not used anywhere else, but how do you explain that I get the memory leak until I call a function? I've already tried nulling it but it doesn't work

Comment: Do you mean you *don’t* get the leak until calling the function? Are you actually crashing your program because of this leak?

Comment: Yes exactly, the leak only shows after calling the function... Not actually crashing but it's consuming a lot of memory

Comment: Well, it’s possible that it’s not really a leak, but just a memory heavy process. If your memory usage grows and grows and never returns to lower levels (garbage collectors only run when certain thresholds are reached iirc), then you have a problem. Otherwise, it’s probably fine.